# Intersection on a range

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I want to make a symbol representing the intersection over the range i = 1 to n (by having i = 1 at the bottom right of the intersection symbol and n at the top right, like a summation)  How do I do this?  Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Like this?

```
\begin{displaymath}
  \bigcap\limits^n_{i=0}
\end{displaymath}
```

If you want to use it as inline math you could write it like this:

```
$\bigcap^n_{i=0}$
```

Since it's a very large symbol I wouln't suggest the inline solution

[image]

Here is a solution creating the output you described

```
{\bigcap}_{i=0}^k
```

[image]

Comment: Not exactly, what I intended, but it accomplishes the same thing.  Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this for inline expression, `$\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}$`

Answer (score 1):

Although not elegant, but gets the job done.

```
$\overset{\infty}{\underset{i=0}{\bigcap}}$
```